# Auto Rig Pro does not bind to character

Tags: rigging

I finished a bind on a character,Then I go to "pose mode" and try to move controller, receive an error message " Cannot change pose when" Rest Position" is enabled(before binding it was on "pose position" and it changes on its own after I bind).

I've tried this multiple times, changed heated to voxel and also went through recommendations on the documentation but I am still having this issue. Please help

Comment: It should work again when you just switch it back to the *Pose Position* mode after binding.

Answer (score 1):

Heated or voxel doesn't have any influence on this, in pose mode just change your armature property from Rest position to Pose position.

[image]